# post file in axios typescript

Tags: typescript, axios, multipartform-data

When I use the POSTMAN to send the file, results of `request.body` and `request.FILES` on server(Django) are as follows.

[image: postman screenshot]

```
# request.body
b'----------------------------428122473547192363129279\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="mnist-8.onnx"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n----------------------------4281224
73547192363129279--\r\n'

# request.FILES
<MultiValueDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: mnist-8.onnx (application/octet-stream)>]}>
```

But I send the file using `axios.post` in Typescript is as follow. What am I doing wrong?

```
const article = createReadStream('C:/Users/USER/Downloads/mnist-8.onnx','utf-8');
const form = new FormData();
form.append('file',article);


axios.post(URL, 
           {form} ,
          {headers: form.getHeaders(),}
          )
        .then(res => {
            console.log(`statusCode: ${res.status}`);
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        })
```

**Result**

```
# request.body
b'{"form":{"_overheadLength":168,"_valueLength":0,"_valuesToMeasure":[{"_readableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":65536,"buffer":{"head":null,"tail":null,"length":0},"length":0,"pipes":[],"flowing":false,"
ended":false,"endEmitted":false,"reading":false,"sync":true,"needReadable":false,"emittedReadable":false,"readableListening":false,"resumeScheduled":false,"errorEmitted":false,"emitClose":true,"autoDestroy":false,"d
estroyed":false,"errored":null,"closed":false,"closeEmitted":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","awaitDrainWriters":null,"multiAwaitDrain":false,"readingMore":false,"decoder":{"encoding":"utf8"},"encoding":"utf-8"},"_ev
ents":{},"_eventsCount":3,"path":"C:/Users/USER/Downloads/mnist-8.onnx","fd":null,"flags":"r","mode":438,"end":null,"autoClose":true,"bytesRead":0,"closed":false}],"writable":false,"readable":true,"dataSize":0,"maxD
ataSize":2097152,"pauseStreams":true,"_released":false,"_streams":["----------------------------491338960963120064647765\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\\"file\\"; filename=\\"mnist-8.onnx\\"\\r\\nContent
-Type: application/octet-stream\\r\\n\\r\\n",{"source":{"_readableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":65536,"buffer":{"head":null,"tail":null,"length":0},"length":0,"pipes":[],"flowing":false,"ended":false,"e
ndEmitted":false,"reading":false,"sync":true,"needReadable":false,"emittedReadable":false,"readableListening":false,"resumeScheduled":false,"errorEmitted":false,"emitClose":true,"autoDestroy":false,"destroyed":false
,"errored":null,"closed":false,"closeEmitted":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","awaitDrainWriters":null,"multiAwaitDrain":false,"readingMore":false,"decoder":{"encoding":"utf8"},"encoding":"utf-8"},"_events":{},"_even
tsCount":3,"path":"C:/Users/USER/Downloads/mnist-8.onnx","fd":null,"flags":"r","mode":438,"end":null,"autoClose":true,"bytesRead":0,"closed":false},"dataSize":0,"maxDataSize":null,"pauseStream":true,"_maxDataSizeExc
eeded":false,"_released":false,"_bufferedEvents":[{"0":"pause"}],"_events":{},"_eventsCount":1},null],"_currentStream":null,"_insideLoop":false,"_pendingNext":false,"_boundary":"--------------------------49133896096
3120064647765"}}'

# request.FILES
<MultiValueDict: {}>
```

Comment: Try to use `FormData`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript

Comment: remove the curly braces from the ```form``` key, so instead of ```{form}``` you should have ```form```

Comment: looking at the log from the python side I'd say ```axios``` is calling ```JSON.stringify()``` on the body ```{form}```. That said, you also might want to explicitly set the ```content-type``` header like so: ```{ headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}```.

Comment: Then the result is like this.
print(request.body)
b''
print(request.FILES)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
,,,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913656/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data-with-file